# Connect two activities in a flow chart on separate pages

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

Is it possible to have an activity that is part of a flow chart connect to an activity that is also part of a flow chart on a separate page (separate flow chart)?

Here's the scenario:  I have a large flow chart.  Because it is large, it's separated into two pages/flow charts.  Each activity is a step.  For example, step 4 connects to a flow decision.  From the flow decision, based on the logic, the next step/activity could be either the next step in the flow (step 5) or it could skip to step 12 (which is on the next page/flow chart).

From a visual standpoint, it would be nice to see the connection, but it's not as necessary.  However, I need to make sure that the WF4 runtime engine is able to follow the flow.  Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have shared functionality between workflows, what I'd do is put the shared aspects into a seperate workflow model.

This way you'll be able to include them as linked models in your workflow for both pages.

Comment: I actually thought that myself as well, but I think there is a complication that might hinder this.  We need to be able to print out the workflow to a document.  Our customers will need to visually see the flow.  With having multiple nested flow charts, it would be difficult to print out cleanly.  That's why we decided to have them as "pages".

Comment: Doing things that way reduces your ability to use the software correctly. What about components that are bound to dynamic models? what about the ability to re-use components. etc etc. In our case we print out each of the workflow diagrams and number the component from which they came. Then everyone can see which component contains its own workflow and what number document to look at.

Comment: I actually number them as (1) for the outer component and (1.1, 1.2) for the inner...then I can have dynamic models as (1.1.1) and everyone can find what they're looking for easily.